# Can I iterate over an Entity's properties in Doctrine2?

Tags: php, doctrine, doctrine-orm

i use

```
$myblogrepo = $this->_doctrine->getRepository('Entities\Blog')->findBy(array('id' => 12);
```

i access via

```
foreach($myblogrepo as $key =>$value){

echo $key . $value;

}
```

how can i get the field names? i thought the key =>  would work but it print s the key as 0

so i thought this would work:

```
foreach($myblogrepo[0] as $key =>$value){

echo $key . $value;
}
```

but still nothing..
}

Answer (score 22, accepted):

In all likelihood, your Blog entity's properties are declared as `protected`.  This is why you can't iterate over them from outside the the Entity itself.

If you're using your Blog entities in a read-only fashion, and only need access to the properties marked as @Columns (read: you don't need to call any methods on your entity), you might consider using array-hydration.  That way you'll be dealing with simple arrays, and `$k=>$v` type iteration will work fine.

Otherwise, you'll need to create some kind of getValues() method on your entity class.  This could be a simple implementation that just builds and array and returns it.

Finally, you could create a general-purpose getValues() as a utility function that uses doctrine's class metadata to figure out what columns and entity has, and operate on those data.  A simple implementation like this:

```
function getEntityColumnValues($entity,$em){
  $cols = $em->getClassMetadata(get_class($entity))->getColumnNames();
  $values = array();
  foreach($cols as $col){
    $getter = 'get'.ucfirst($col);
    $values[$col] = $entity->$getter();
  }
  return $values;
}
```

**EDIT** - A more mature version of the above method seems to be [available here](https://github.com/borisguery/bgylibrary/blob/master/library/Bgy/Doctrine/EntitySerializer.php) - I've not played with it yet, but it looks promising.

Answer (score 2):

If you just need to get the properties of the entity in a fast and easy way, this is what I do in my projects:

All my entities inherit from an EntityBase class, which has the following method:

```
public function toValueObject()
{
    $result = new \stdClass();
    foreach ($this as $property => $value) {
        $getter = 'get' . ucfirst($property);
        if (method_exists($this, $getter)) {
            $result->$property = $this->$getter();
        }
    }
    return $result;
}
```

So all I have to do is call `$entity->toValueObject()` and I obtain a standard object with all of the entity's properties as public properties.

Answer (score 1):

Use `findOneBy` instead of `findBy` to select a single row.

```
$myblogrepo = $this->_doctrine->getRepository('Entities\Blog')->findOneBy(array('id' => 12);
```

Your key was `0` because it was the first row in a possible multi-row result.

Comment: tried that too, but you cant foreach that, you can just access it via: $myblogrepo->id   but this is the value, how can i get teh keyname? or field name?

Comment: Do `$iterableResult = $myblogrepo->iterate();` and use `foreach ($iterableResult as $key => $value)` to iterate over values. http://www.doctrine-project.org/docs/orm/2.0/en/reference/batch-processing.html#iterating-large-results-for-data-processing

Comment: And you can absolutely iterate over an object with `foreach`. Just try it.

Comment: just done that.  Notice: Undefined property: Entities\Blog::$iterate

Comment: make sure you use `$myblogrepo->iterate();` and not `$myblogrepo->iterate;`. `iterate()` is a method, not a property.

Comment: i have , still the same error.  do i need to add this method in my entities or something.. i am using iterate()

Answer (score 0):

This is a my implementation of a serializer class that also check if it is a doctrine entity:

```
/**
 * JsonApiSerializer constructor.
 * @param EntityManagerInterface $em
 */
public function __construct(EntityManagerInterface $em)
{
    $this->em = $em;
}

/**
 * @param $payLoad
 * @return string
 */
public function serialize($payLoad, $type)
{
    $serializedPayload = new \stdClass();
    $serializedPayload->data = new \stdClass();

    $serializedPayload->data->type = $type;

    if ($this->isDoctrineEntity($payLoad)) {
        $this->addEntityColumnValues($serializedPayload, $payLoad);
    }

    return json_encode($serializedPayload);
}

private function isDoctrineEntity($payLoad)
{
    if (is_object($payLoad)) {
        $payLoad = ($payLoad instanceof Proxy)
            ? get_parent_class($payLoad)
            : get_class($payLoad);
    }

    return !$this->em->getMetadataFactory()->isTransient($payLoad);
}

private function addEntityColumnValues(&$serializedPayload, $entity){
    $serializedPayload->data->attributes = new \stdClass();

    $classMetaData = $this->em->getClassMetadata(get_class($entity));
    $columnNames = $classMetaData->getColumnNames();
    foreach($columnNames as $columnName){
        $fieldName = $classMetaData->getFieldForColumn($columnName);
        $getter = 'get'.ucfirst($fieldName);
        $serializedPayload->data->attributes->$columnName = $entity->$getter();
    }
}
```